Can I move disks from one HP DL160 Gen9 Server to another DL160 Gen9 on a RAID 5 setup without data loss?
Would it be possible to move disks from one HP DL160 Gen9 Server to another DL160 Gen9 on a RAID 5 setup with 4 disks in a straight forward manner?
We have experienced a sudden failure which started out with a Windows crash and then a failure to boot a couple of times which quickly became a critical error pointing to the SAS Controller. Within 20 minutes the Server failed to power on beyond the flashing red health light.
I have another HP DL160 Gen9 with the exact same Hardware setup.
I have read that it should be straight forward to the move the disks from the failed Server to new and the configuration will move across on a HP environment? Is this the case or more complicated as it used to be with RAIDS of old.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

this normal for equipment who h afaik EOL from the vendor, if I been correctly informed it has reached 2022 it's EOL which would make the question off topic. usually if you have a backup from the raid config you should be able to restore it. if not use your backup to restore it.... and no backup no.... you know the drill. ;)

Should it work? Yes.

It's less about the base system and more about the RAID controller model - what's that?

Yes, you’ll be fine! Just make sure to run a backup and test the restore process before experimenting with your live data migration.
P.S. When you have the ability to, of course…

If the RAID adapter in question is some HP/Compaq SmartArray HW RAID, then yes, it will work, just transfer the disks properly.
